# What does $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=3$ mean?

Tags: asymptotics, infinite-graphs

What I did was to see that the function is behaving as a straight line with gradient $3$ at infinity which implies that the function has an oblique asymptote as $x \to \infty$ but my testing portal says the answer is wrong and that instead, the function is infinite of order $1$ with respect to $x$. I think both of these are correct otherwise I must be confusing terminologies here[image]

Comment: what does it mean "to be an infinite of order 1 at infinity" ? Is it $\mathcal O(x)$ ?

Comment: i think it means that the order of the principal part at infinity is 1

Comment: Consider $f(x)=3 x+ \log(x)$ which has $f'(x) = 3 +\frac1x \to 3$.  Try to find the oblique asymptote

Comment: @M.HamzaAli Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in order to have a **oblique asymptotes**

- $y=mx+n$ with $m,n\in \mathbb{R}$.

with

$$m=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$

and

$$n=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} (f(x)-mx)$$

both limit must exist.

Note that since the function is evantually strictly increasing $f(x)\to +\infty$ thus

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}= \lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f'(x)=3$$

thus $f(x)=\mathcal O(x)$.

Comment: if the function is behaving as a straight line does it mean that c also exists?

Comment: @M.HamzaAli It is not a sufficient condition, think to the example given in the commentd $f(x)=3x+log x$

Answer (score 1):

The existence of an oblique asymptote is too strong. The derivative may approach 3 while the graph is not necessarily asymptotic to the line y=3x+b. It may oscillate and cross that line infinitely many times.

Comment: Crossing an asymptote is less of an issue than it not existing

Comment: True, I meant the hypothetical asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a function on $\mathbb R$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$ but does not have a horizontal asymptote is $\log(1+x^2)$. If you prefer $f'(x) = 3$, try
$$f(x) = 3x+\log(1+x^2).$$